# Upload folder from PC to a storage account container using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

Trying to upload a folder from my pc to a container in my storage account. Did some digging around and this is what I have attempted so far.

```
az storage blob upload-batch --destination {STORAGE_CONTAINER} --account-name {ACCOUNT_NAME} 
--destination-path {STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME} --source {local_directory}
```

Most of it is pretty straight forward but I am wondering about what the destination-path is. The following is the information I got from `--help`, so I am wondering if it is the storage container name?

```
The destination path that will be prepended to the blob name.
```

Comment: What happened after you set the `--destination-path`?

Answer (score 1):

> Most of it is pretty straight forward but I am wondering about what
> the destination-path is.

`destination-path` is the virtual folder where your blobs will be uploaded.

For example, let's say you have a blob container named `static-content` and you want to upload some images inside it but you want those images to go inside `images` folder inside that container. That's when you will set `destination-path` to `images`.

What this script will do is prepend the value of the destination path to the name of the blob. For example, if you are uploading `logo.png` and the destination-path is set as `images`, then the name of your blob will be `images/logo.png` and the blob URL would be `https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/images/logo.png`.